# Just Smart contract driven app is a DAPP?

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, contract-deployment, dapp-development, dapp-design

I have same years working as a Java & JS fullstack developer, but I'm totally new to Ethereum's development, and I'm trying to figure out how to architect a Dapp (Smart contracts driven app).

It's OK and enough for considering a web application a Dapp, to have a centralized server/cloud (AWS for example) running a web app that it's talking with different smart contracts (living in Ethereum's Blockchain), via HTTP requests on eth.contract({...}) JavaScript object's function?

Thanks too much.

Comment: Hi, not sure if it's just me, but I'm having difficulty understanding your question; it may help if you can reword your question or add more details.

Comment: I'm asking about basic DAPP architecture. Backend in a server, with code talking with Smart Contracts and with any DB like SQL/Nosql, or IPFS to keep data decentralized. Any decentralized cloud/hosting for Node or Java Web Apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DApp stands for decentralized application.

The decentralized bit is the fact that it runs on the blockchain. I.E. The smart contracts.

Most DApps have smart contracts on the Ethereum blockchain, and a frontend for interfacing with those smart contracts.

Most Ethereum clients ([Geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/geth), and [Parity](https://parity.io/) for example) implement the [JSON RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) APIs and thus you can communicate with a node using any programming language.

Javascript is commonly used by proxy of the [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) library.

Your understanding is completely correct.

Comment: Thanks too much for the answer. When I storage/check data (like) of my Dapp (business data, user profile info...) can I do it with a centralized database server (like MySQL) from my centralized server running the dapp (in Spring Boot or Node JS requesting to Smart contracts), keeping considered as a DAPP?

Comment: Yes. You can do as you please. The point is that blockchain is only useful for your project if you decentralize the things that need to be decentralized. If nothing needs to be decentralized then don't use it.

Comment: I'm asking about basic DAPP architecture. Backend in a server, with code talking with Smart Contracts and with any DB like SQL/Nosql,  or IPFS to keep data decentralized. Any decentralized cloud/hosting for Node or Java Web Apps?

Comment: Yes, that is fine..

Answer (score 0):

Decentralized applications come in multiple forms. Smart contracts are the most pure since they run entirely on the blockchain. However sometimes you want to have apps that interact with the blockchain externally. So you would use Geth or the Infura apis to interact directly with Ethereum. These are still decentralized applications, but they can be written in any language.